# OPENCV стек в KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: c++, opencv

работаю на VC++2010 после компиляции выдаёт ошибку Необработанное исключение в "0x751ec54f" в "OPCV.exe": Исключение Microsoft C++: cv::Exception по адресу 0x0038f3f8..
загрузил все библиотеки, на синтаксисе нету(IntelliSence) ошибок
пожалуйста помогите решить эту проблему
Source:

```
 #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 int main(int argc, const char** argv)
 {     
   // load image and convert to gray scale  
    Mat inImg = imread("pic.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat outImg = imread("pic.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if (inImg.empty())
{
    cout << "Error: cannot load source image!\n";
    return -1;
}



    for( int y = 0; y < inImg.rows; y++ ) {
      for( int x = 0; x < inImg.cols; x++ ) {
         // remove the following line, and add your code to process the input image  
          if ((inImg.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0]+inImg.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1]+inImg.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2])/3>80)
          {
            outImg.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = 0;
          }
          else
            outImg.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = 255;

        }
     }
    imshow("Result: ", outImg);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Трассируйте - найдется ошибка. Ошибка у вас времени выполнения.

Comment: А как это сделать, можете объяснить